# How to bind scrollbar bottom in wxPython ListCtrl

Tags: wxpython

I'm a beginner in wxPython but I don't figure out how to bind one event.

I want to bind this "EVT_SCROLL_BOTTOM" from a ListCtrl...

From the documentation it seems there is no way to do it. ListCtrl doesn't inherit ScrollEvent.. But is there a way to workaroud?

How to bind an event from vertical ScrollBar in ListCtrl?

Should I create my own ListCtrl Class and add ScrollEvent inheritance?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned here: [wx.ScrollEvent documentation](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ScrollEvent-class.html), ScrollEvents are only emmited by stand-alone scrollbars and sliders.

However [wx.ScrollWinEvents](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ScrollWinEvent-class.html) are emitted by Scrolling Windows such as a wx.ListCtrl.

So in order to get the desired result you should bind the  wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN_BOTTOM to your List Ctrl like so:

```
ListCtrlVariable.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN_BOTTOM, self.FooEventHandler)
```

Comment: You right I have to bind directly from the ListCtrl and not from my Frame... It looks logic btw!